# mysql ERROR 3680 (HY000): Failed to create schema directory

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image]

Im trying to create database using mysql but getting this error

ERROR 3680 (HY000): Failed to create schema directory 'XXX' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory)

Comment: trying HOW??? More specific information required please

Comment: hey, added some info. Im new to mysql sorry I did not get what you were asking

Comment: Looks like it might be a premission issue if you are on a *nix machine

Comment: hey, im using macOS

Comment: Well thats a *nix

Comment: Is it possible that you already have created that said database try `use XXX` It also seems like you have permission issues `chmod 644` might help you

Answer (score 3):

Try to reboot your computer and use(**systemctl**) this to start mysql :

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

Comment: Restarting the MySQL service worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could `ps -ef` and list all PID, found the `mysql` PID and `sudo kill -9 [mysql_pid]`